# F# Matching on possible generic list or sequence types

Tags: f#

I am trying figure out if a generic type wrapped in a rop result is a list or not. This is what I tried but I got errors.

```
let checkType (result : RopResult<'tSuccess, 'errors>) =
    match result with
    | Success (s, msg) ->
        match s with
        | :? [] -> // error here
```

Sample

```
let isList<'s> () = true
let processList (ls : 'domain list) = true
let processType (s : 'domain) = true

let checkType (result : RopResult<'tSuccess, 'errors>) =
    match result with
    | Success (s, msg) ->
        match s with
        | s when isList<s>() -> processList s
        | _ -> processType s
    | Failure (x) -> false
```

Comment: You already have the type statically, you can just test `typeof<'tSuccess>`. But I feel like you're doing it the wrong way. Can you please elaborate on the bigger problem? _Why_ do you need to determine if it's a list?

Comment: In order to choose the subsequent function that will take 'tSuccess as an input. I have 2 functions in mind. One that will process a list and one that doesn't.  Maybe I am on the wrong path, but nevertheless I'm still unclear on how to properly pattern match against possible types.

Comment: Here's an exercise for you: imagine that you have a magic way to determine whether `tSuccess` is a list or not. Say there is a function `isList<'a>()`. Now that you have that function, what would be your next step? Try to write the code that will follow.

Comment: if it is a list then I would apply a function that takes a list or provide a function to a List.map along with the list in question.

Comment: Try to write the code. See if it compiles. Post this code in the text of the question.

Comment: not sure I follow but I updated the code.

Comment: Did you try to compile it? Does it compile?

Comment: Look, I'm still getting my head around F#. I'm confused now. Why would that psuedo code compile. It's not at all obvious to me.

Comment: I'm trying to get you to think your problem through. My experience shows that what you think you need is not what you actually need. So I'm trying to get you to think about your problem to the end, that will help you see where the actual disconnect is. Declare a stub for this function (i.e. `let isList<'a>() = true`) and then try to write your actual code as if you already had this function. You'll see.

Comment: So the code did not compile. The Error I received is the type is not defined.

Comment: You said 'pattern match against possible types', that's wrong. You don't pattern match over different types, unless you do a dynamic type test which is not the case. You pattern match on different shapes on the same type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll first explain the technicalities of how to get your code to work, and then try to convince you (as the other folks on this thread) that it may not be the right way to approach your problem.

Firstly, your match statement has a syntax error. You would write the type test and the cast in one swoop as

```
match s with
| :? List<int> as theIntList -> ...do something with theIntList ...
```

When you add that to your code, the F# compiler will complain "The runtime coercion or type test ... involves an indeterminate type. ... Further type annotations are needed". Fix that by being more specific about what kind of result your `checkType` is processing: it is some `System.Object` instance and the message, so you'd write:

```
let checkType (result : Result<obj*string, 'errors>) =
    match result with
    | Success (s, msg) ->
        match s with
        | :? List<int> as theIntList -> ... do something
```

Note that you can't change that to a generic thing like `List<_>` - F# will do the type test *and* the cast in one go, and would not hence know what to cast to. If you try to, you will see warnings that your `List<_>` has been inferred to be `List<obj>`

Having said all that: Using `obj` is not the idiomatic way to go, as others have tried to point out already. The answers of @robkuz and @TheInnerLight contain all you need: A `map` function, functions that operate on individual result types, which then becomes nicely composable:

```
let map f x = 
    match x with
    | Success (s, msg) -> Success (f s, msg)
    | Failure f -> Failure f

// This will automatically be inferred to be of type Result<(int list * string), 'a>
let myFirstResult = Success ([1;2], "I've created an int list")
// This will automatically be inferred to be of type Result<(string list * string), 'a>
let mySecondResult = Success (["foo"; "bar"], "Here's a string list")
// Process functions for specific result types. No type tests needed!
let processIntList (l: int list) = Seq.sum l
let processStringList = String.concat "; "
// This will automatically be inferred to be of type Result<(int * string), 'a>
let mapFirst = myFirstResult |> map processIntList
// This will automatically be inferred to be of type Result<(string * string), 'a>
let mapSecond = mySecondResult |> map processStringList
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if I really understand your problem.
In general if you have some polymorphic type (like your `RopResult`) and you want to process the polymorphic part of it a good approach in F# would be
to disentagle your code into a wrapper code and a processor code where your processor code is delivered via a higher order function for the processing part.

Example:

```
type RopResult<'tSuccess, 'tError> =
    | Success of 'tSuccess
    | Error of 'tError

let checkType (process: 'tSuccess -> 'tResult) (result : RopResult<'tSuccess, 'tError>) =
    match result with
    | Success s -> process s |> Success
    | Error e -> Error e
```

and

```
let processList (ls : 'domain list) = true
let processType (s : 'domain) = true
```

and then you

```
checkType processList aListWrappedInResult
checkType processType aTypeWrappedInResult
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you wanted to determine whether a supplied value was of a generic list type, you could do this:

```
let isList value =
    let valueType = value.GetType()
    match valueType.IsGenericType with
    |true -> valueType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() = typedefof<_ list>
    |false -> false
```

Example usage:

> ```
> isList [5];;
> val it : bool = true
> isList ["a", "b"];;
> val it : bool = true
> isList "a";;
> val it : bool = false
> ```

When working with something like `RopResult`, or more formally, `Either`, it's helpful to define the `map` function.  The `map` function takes a function `'a -> 'b` and gives you a function which operates in some elevated domain, e.g. `RopResult<'a,'c> -> RopResult<'b,'c>`.

This is analogous to `List.map : ('a ->'b) -> 'a List -> 'b List`.

We define it like this:

```
let map f v =
    match v with
    |Success sv -> Success (f sv)
    |Failure fv -> Failure (fv)
```

You can then use `isList` on `RopResult`s by simply doing:

```
ropResult |> map isList
```

---

Others here are warning you in the comments that there may be potential issues surrounding how you actually process the results once you've determined whether the type is a list or not.  Specifically, you will need to ensure that the return types of your `processList` and `processType` functions are the same (although I would recommend revisiting the naming of `processType` and call it `processValue` instead.  Since you are not operating on the type, I think the name is confusing).